# Why is WxPythons motion detection so slow?

Tags: python, wxpython

I set the `on_motion` to handle `EVT_MOTION`. I want the mouse location for **interactively** generating a coordinate-specific image, but WxPython has a **~400ms** delay in registering successive motion events. Which makes the interface sluggish.

Why is `EVT_MOTION` so slow and how do I fix it? I tried it in Ubuntu 11.10 and WinXP and the delays are comparable?

I need fast response times for selecting a portion from an image like the picture shows. As it stands, the "cross-hairs" follow the mouse too slowly.

[image]

Here is the code which I tried `EVT_MOTION`:

```
def on_motion(self, event):
    """mouse in motion"""
    #pt = event.GetPosition()
    self.mouseover_location = event.GetPosition()
    self.t2 = time.time()
    print "delay",self.t2 - self.t1
    self.t1 = self.t2

delay 0.379776954651
delay 0.00115919113159
delay 0.421130895615
delay 0.416938066483
delay 0.376848936081
delay 0.387464046478
delay 0.40311384201
delay 0.392899036407
delay 0.385301113129
delay 0.422554969788
delay 0.355197906494
```

Comment: Could it be other events that are being handled in between? maybe some expensive drawing thats happening perhaps

Comment: I would cross-post to the wxPython Google Group. And post a small runnable example too.

Comment: Have you considered creating a thread devoted only to tracking the mouse? A cosntant loop of "where is the mouse? trigger update. repeat". If the problem is EVT_MOTION this will solve it. If the problem is drawing speed then you should be able to see that too.

Comment: Calling GetPosition isn't taking ~.4seconds to call, as your not timing the on_motion event itself but the time between the current and last motion event. It will be other parts that are slow that process in between the motion events, im guessing the drawing of the crosshairs. Can you post a runable example that has the slowdown? It should just be a case of optimising the drawing

Comment: Without knowing what else is going on, it's impossible to tell why it's taking so long. You need to tell us what else you're doing. A small runnable example app would help tremendously.

Comment: To see the real granularity of motion events, try disabling all screen handling (crosshairs etc) and just run your timing code blind. Is it still slow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question as it stands is incomplete, as there is no sample app to demonstrate the problem. However, I would say that the motion handler has got nothing to do with your problem, because most likely you are doing some expensive operation between subsequent motion handlers (like refreshing your entire drawing canvas).

If this is the case (and you can easily check if your paint routine is called between mouse motion events), I would suggest the following:

1. If your drawing that stuff yourself, ensure that you are using double buffering (via wx.BufferedPaintDC);
2. If your paint routine is indeed called between mouse motions, try and refresh only the damaged portion of your plot (via RefreshRect);
3. Use wx.Overlay to draw your rectangular selection (there are a few demos available on how to do that);
4. Post a small, runnable sample app that demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Yes, it was an expensive drawing operation that needs 0.35 seconds. I pared it down to 0.1 and its smoother. I assumed the event detection operates asynchronously with respect to the drawing (and works like true multithreading). And I call `Refresh()` whenever I acquire a new image.

Answer (score 2):

The `EVT_MOTION` is fired every time the mouse is moved! If you then call `event.GetPosition()` on every movement and also process the data, this will slow down performance. 
How would it be to use `EVT_LEFT_DOWN` or something similar, and then get the position and process that data. 
This will be much more efficient since you are only looking for a certain area of the image.

Comment: _"If you then call event.GetPosition() on every movement and also process the data"_ please elaborate on this. I do need guides to pinpoint the crosshairs, atleast when the user comes near (with his pointer) the desired point.

Comment: In that case you would need to make your "drawing code" faster. Try commenting out things and see if the speed is improving. If you cannot make it faster in a single thread, try adding another one.

Answer (score 2):

We'll really need to see what else is going on in the application to be able to give you any meaningful answers, although many people are able to solve the problems themselves in the process of creating a small sample demonstrating the problem to share with others.

http://wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps

Optimizing how you are drawing the cross-hairs and/or how you are refreshing the main content of the window is probably your best bet, but until you share more details all we can do is guess.